# How to get values inside nested braces using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string having list of expressions inside braces. I want to get the details by splitting it in an array.
I have tried like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
sub main() {
my $string = <STDIN>; 
while ($string =~ /(\((?:(?1)|[^()]*+)++\))|[^()\s]++/g) 
{
print "$&\n" 
}
main();

InPut : (+ (+ 4 3) ( - 3 2) 5)
Output should be : (+ (+ 3 4) ( - 2 3) 5)
(+ 3 4)
( - 2 3)
```

which i'm trying to store it in an array and then evaluate seprately.. But not sure thats the right approach.

Basically i'm trying to evaluate an expression as below.

```
4+3 =7 , 3-2 =1 , and then 7+1+5 = 13
Final output should be 13
```

Can any one kindly help me on this?

Comment: You cannot get captures of all nesting levels simultaneously, just like you can't get multiple captures with something like `(.)+` (you'd only get the last character). You could match outermost brackets and recursively continue matching their contents. But I suppose its easier to parse something like this manually. [Have a look at this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=997089)

Comment: @m.buettner: it's not that hard, have a look at my answer below.

Comment: If the OP is looking unbounded nesting, then it's very hard. Regular expressions don't have the power to do unbounded nesting. Only a parser, that is, a finite-state automation with a push-down stack can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following expression `/(?=(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\)))/g`

See it in action here: http://regex101.com/r/eI7iP5

Comment: Link broken, please fix.

Comment: Gad, I can't believe someone was foolish enough to put recursion in (ir)regular expressions. That would make them Turing complete. And with no place for comments. Reminds me of APL, the write only language.

Comment: @Lindrian the lookahead is a nice idea. +1!